# link_to syntax in Rails 4 for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

I really don't understand how to link to another view in rails.

I load datas in /products/index.html.erb and want to retrieve product id form one product to point to another view : subjects/index.html.erb

what is the correct syntax to have this url with the link_to : '/products/9/subjects' (for product id 9) ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you have nested routes defined as your question seems so:

```
<%= link_to "Click", [@product, :subjects] %>
```

Comment: Ok found the solution, i replace @product by p because i was in a loop :`@products.each do |p| and now works !!! `

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
link_to "Click", subjects_product_path(9)
```

If you use rake routes it'll tell you which routes you have available you'd need nested resources for this to work

```
resources :products do
  resources :subjects
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

```
<%= link_to "The name of your link", product_subjects_path(9) %>
```

Where 9 is the id of your product. You can use more generic link like:

```
<%= link_to "The name of your link", product_subjects_path(@product) %>
```

in a show view of a product, or even:

```
<h2>Links to subjects for each product </h2>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
    <%= link_to product.title, product_subjects_path(product) %>
<% end %>
```

in an index.

Assuming that in your routes you have subjects nested under products:

```
resources :products do
  resources :subjects
end
```

Don't forget when you are lost with your routes:

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

will give you all existing routes.

Here is the rails guide about routing with nested: [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Here is the documentation for the syntax of the path: [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects)

Comment: <%= link_to "The name of your link", product_subjects_path(9) %> Returns an error  [@product, :subjects] works it's really complicated to understand when we are newbie ! Why we use [@product, :subjects] in this syntax ??

Comment: Assuming you are using      @products.each do |p|  can you try      <%= link_to "The name of your link", product_subjects_path(p) %> This is the syntax i usually use in my app, i'll check for the another notation

Comment: Here is a doc for path and url, you'll find the short version of a link with the helper ( [p, :subjects] in your case ): [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects). It's just a shorter way to write the link_to.

Answer (score 0):

To see all the routes in your rails application just use the following command:

```
rake routes
```

It will list all the routes along with the routes variables and the controller/action that they point to. From there you take the name of the route and append an _path or _url (in case you neeed an absolute url) in roder to obtain the name of the method to use in the link_to.

In your case the link_to for the /products/9/subjects path is:

```
link_to 'Link text', product_subjects_path(@product)
```